# Python: keys for a function vs multiple functions?

Tags: python, function

What is the general consensus on this:

```
def stock_amend(self, key, quantity):
    if key == "add":
        self.stock_quantity += quantity
    elif key == "remove":
        self.stock_quantity -= quantity
    ...
```

VS

```
def stock_add(self, quantity):
    self.stock_quantity += quantity

def stock_remove(self, quantity):
    self.stock_quantity -= quantity

...
```

Which of the two is a better way to define simple, similar functions? Using a keyword or just defining multiple functions?

Comment: I would probably go for the two separate functions for readability. I think its much easier to use stock_remove(4) or stock_add(4), then to do stock_amend("remove",4) and  stock_amend("add",4). But for me, it would mainly be for the readability.

Comment: Readability is one of the most important things in the successful project usually, so yeah, go with the 2nd option. it is easier to read and to reason about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I'm most used to seeing it is with classes:

```
class Stock:
    def add(self, quantity):
        self.stock_quantity += quantity
    def remove(self, quantity):
        self.stock_quantity -= quantity
```

Or if the logic is extremely similar, you could just make a change method:

```
def stock_change(self, delta):
    self.stock_quantity += delta
```

and pass negative values to it to effect a negative change.

One think you want to be very careful about though is making sure you have a clean api. As the boundary between different parts of your program, it's often the hardest part of your program to change. Generally, you want a function to only do one thing. This is called the Single Responsibility principle. Before you continue, Google "how to design an API" and read up on people's thoughts on it. Many of those opinions were forged with hard-won experience.

It ultimately depends on what *you* want. You know more about your app than I do.

I don't consider myself an expert, but I do have an opinion. Mods, if this is too opinion based/not helpful, please edit/remove it.

If the stock is a small relatively unimportant part of your code, I would probably go with the `stock_change` method (maybe rename it to something that describes a linear change to a stock, so later if you want to to say, increase a stock by 10%, which is also a "stock_change", you'll have less ambiguous function names). The reason I suggest this is because it's less code and you can refactor it later to the second method later if you need to (assuming you aren't distributing this to customers yet). Google "YAGNI".

If you're doing a lot of things with a stock though, it would be better to make it its own class. Then you can subclass it, group other similar "stocky" functionality to it, et cetera. Google "Why OOP".

Unless you have a very good reason, I would avoid using the string as part of your API. Strings as an API argument are hard to refactor- they're already used for user input as well as output (and probably other things I'm not thinking about now), and many a programmer has struggled to understand which strings are which. In addition, remember that *any* string can be passed to your api and you'll have to filter for it each time. They are very weakly typed. Instead, consider [enums](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html) if you want to use an approach with most (all?) of string's advantages but still be able to limit the amount of stuff passed to your functions.

In summary, each of the above approaches has advantages and disadvantages. There are probably more approaches I haven't considered as well (I don't consider myself an expert on this stuff), but you know your problem domain the most here, and even if you get it wrong this time, you'll be able to learn from it next time. Just keep reading, keep refactoring, and you'll learn what make a good API and a bad one.

Comment: Updating the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches possible, e.g. sending a function to `stock_amend` that actually makes the modification, and so on.

Unless we need higher flexibility (provided by #1) **it's reasonable to have things defined at compilation time** (#2) to allow easier static analysis, simpler code review, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Can I recommend a 3rd approach using **operator** module?

```
import operator

mapping = {
    'add': operator.add,
    'remove': operator.neg,
}

def stock_amend(self, key, quantity):
    return mapping.get(key)(self.stock_quantity, quantity)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, really, it just gives an alternate implementation of the `stock_amend` function...

Comment: so why alternative implementation cannot be the answer to the question?

Comment: How does it anser the question "What is the preferred approach, approach 1 or approach 2"? You simply replied "here is an alternative implementation of approach 2", see what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Passing around strings is a bad pattern. Either the caller will have to memorize all the possible keys or they will have to visit its definition in source. You may remember these values for now, but after a while we always tend to forget these things and anyone new working on the code is also going to have a hard time as well. With separate definitions the autocomplete provided by most editors will do the job for you and in shell `dir()` and `help()` will help.

Apart from that you may have to add few conditions in future in these functions, having just one function would make it even more complex.

```
def stock_add(self, quantity):
    assert quantity > 0
    self.stock_quantity += quantity

def stock_remove(self, quantity):
    assert quantity > 0 and self.stock_quantity - quantity >= 0
    self.stock_quantity -= quantity
```

If you have multiple functions doing almost the same thing you can write the common logic in a private method.

```
def _update_stock_quantity(self, quantity):
    self.stock_quantity += quantity

def stock_add(self, quantity):
    assert quantity > 0
    self._update_stock_quantity(quantity)

def stock_remove(self, quantity):
    assert quantity > 0 and self.stock_quantity - quantity >= 0
    self._update_stock_quantity(-quantity)
```

---

Remember that *Code is read more than it is written*.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest defining multiple functions because it keeps your code clear + concise which makes for more powerful code. Each function should have a specific task and should not be reliant on something such as keyword. This will also allow you to reuse your functions in other programs more readily. Below I wrote a way to access each function without `if` and `elif` statements so that your code is not repetitive.

```
class Stock():

    def __init__(self,stock_quantity):
        self.stock_quantity = stock_quantity

    def stock_add(self, quantity):
        self.stock_quantity += quantity

    def stock_remove(self, quantity):
        self.stock_quantity -= quantity

    def update(self,interact,quantity=0):
        try:
            getattr(self,interact)(quantity)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        except TypeError:
            print(getattr(self,interact))



def main():

    stock_obj = Stock(5)

    stock_obj.update("stock_quantity")
    stock_obj.update("stock_add",1)
    stock_obj.update("stock_quantity")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```